# Javascript variables in HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I know there are a lot of posts about this, but I can't find an answer to my specific problem.

I would like to make a JS variable the value of an HTML attribute:

```
<script> var screenWidth = screen.width </script> 

<img src="images/title.png" width="VARIABLE HERE" style="margin-top: 3%"`
```

`"VARIABLE HERE"` is where I would want the `screenWidth` variable to go. What is the best of going about this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>var screenWidth = screen.width;</script> 
...
<img src="images/title.png" onload="this.width=screenWidth;" style="margin-top: 3%">
```

Comment: Isn't there missing something? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp

Answer (score 5):

Give the tag an id.

i.e. `<img id="xxxx" ...>`

Then use

```
 document.getElementById('xxx').setAttribute('width', 'somevalue')
```

See [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

*Or use JQuery as the other poster noted*

Answer (score 4):

You can add the style using javascript to particular element like this.

**script**

```
document.getElementById('myImg').style.width = screen.width + "px";
```

**Html**

```
<img id="myImg" src="images/title.png"  style="margin-top: 3%">
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hCgL9/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply call a JavaScript variable inside your HTML. You'll need to have it written by JavaScript or JQuery. You can do it this way :-

```
 <input id="myInput" .../>
 <script>
    var myVar = "value";
    $("#myInput").attr("name", myVar);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could set the width to either `100vw` using CSS (possibly via the style attribute: `style="width: 100vw;"`. This is more efficient and more readable, but [isn't supported in some old browsers](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).