# Assign variable to an attribute in div tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables, attributes

I have the following code.

My requirement is to fetch the path that is stored in the `myValue` variable and assign it to the `w3-include-html` attribute in `div` tag.

However, I am not able to assign the path presented in myValue to the `w3-include-html` attribute in the `div` tag.

I tried the solutions presented in [Javascript variables in HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643920/javascript-variables-in-html-attributes). This link discusses about img tag. I tried the same solutions for div tag but unable to solve my problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    var myValue = "Tables/"+"FileName"+".html";
</script>   
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div w3-include-html=myValue></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign a class or id to the div involved?

Comment: Your html syntax is a bit off. `myValue` should be enclosed in quotes. Not saying that's the root of your problem but just a nice to know thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript variables in HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643920/javascript-variables-in-html-attributes)

Comment: Make sure your browser supports this tag

Comment: @Jeroen Heier assigning id helped me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that assigns the value (via [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)) to the div any time the function is fired:

```js
var myValue = 'Tables/' + 'FileName' + '.html';

var div = document.querySelector('div[w3-include-html]');

console.log('Value before function call: ' + div.getAttribute('w3-include-html'));

insertMyValue();

console.log('Value after function call: ' + div.getAttribute('w3-include-html'));

function insertMyValue() {
  div.setAttribute('w3-include-html', myValue);
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <div w3-include-html="myValue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the id as shown below:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div id="schema"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var myValue = "Tables/"+"Thing"+".html";
document.getElementById("schema").setAttribute('w3-include-html',myValue);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add an interval and check value and it will check updates automatically.
Some code example:

```js
var myValue = "Tables/"+"FileName"+".html", element = document.querySelector('div[w3-include-html]');
function checkUpdate () {
  if (myValue !== element.getAttribute('w3-include-html')) {
      element.setAttribute('w3-include-html', myValue)
      console.log('updated to %s', myValue);
  }
};

setInterval(checkUpdate, 100);

setTimeout(() => myValue = "Test", 200); // only for example of update.
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div w3-include-html=myValue></div>
    </div>
</div>
```